# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Bridged networking host DNS not working after reboot

Tags: networking, network-manager, dns, qemu

I seem to have a bit of an odd situation here. I just setup bridged networking on my Ubuntu desktop using nmcli, and everything was great until I rebooted. I set it up so that the bridged network allows the guest VMs to connect directly to the local network, and appear as regular machines.

The guests are working perfectly, which is what I was hoping for. The host was fine, until I rebooted and now DNS does not work work. Everything I've checked shows that it should be fine, but I can't figure out why it's not picking up any of the DNS servers.

I've tried changing my /etc/systemd/resolved.conf to include the DNS servers, but that came to no avail. I tried manually setting the IPv4 DNS in NetworkManager, yet nothing is working.

The guide in question I used to set it up is located here, https://gist.github.com/plembo/f7abd2d9b6f76e7afdece02dae7e5097, and I used this same guide on a second machine and it's working just fine so I have no idea why this isn't working.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you have one VM working but not this one, what did you do differently? Have you done a side-my-side comparison? That guide shows DNS configuration via `nmcli`. So why are you editing elsewhere with NetworkManager or `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf`?